# Related Rate Problem Involving Conical tank Formula. I do not understand why this is incorrect.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, related-rates

**A right conical tank with the point oriented down, a height of 15 feet, and a radius of 4 feet has sprung a leak. How fast is the volume of water in the tank changing when the water is 2 feet high and the water level changes at a rate of 14 inches per minute?**

My result was

896π/225

This is apparently incorrect.

The following equation I used was

$$ \frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}pi(\frac{4h}{15})^2(\frac{dH}{dt})$$

Comment: well it would be a ***lot*** easier to tell you ***why*** you're incorrect if you ... showed us how to got to that answer ...

Comment: The result is incorrect at least because it’s missing unit.

Comment: I didn't include proper units because they are on the Webwork Software.

Comment: Now you have added an equation, may I ask what values of $h$ and $\frac{dH}{dt}$ did you put to get $\frac{896\pi}{225}$?

Comment: Now you are on the software of StackExchange, and you can finally include proper units.

Comment: for $$\frac{dH}{dt}$$ I had 14in/min.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From

$$\begin{align*}
\frac rh &= \frac{4}{15}\\
V &= \frac13 \pi r^2h\\
&= \frac13\pi \left(\frac{4h}{15}\right)^2h
\end{align*}$$

Differentiating $V$ with respect to $t$ gives

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dV}{dt} &= \frac13\pi \left[\left(\frac{4h}{15}\right)^2\cdot\frac{dh}{dt} + h\cdot 2\left(\frac{4h}{15}\right)\cdot\frac{4}{15}\frac{dh}{dt}\right]\\
&= \frac13 \pi\cdot 3\left(\frac{4h}{15}\right)^2\cdot\frac{dh}{dt}\\
&= \pi\left(\frac{4h}{15}\right)^2\frac{dh}{dt}\\
\end{align*}$$

(Using product rule and chain rule; same result if you first simplify $V$ as a multiple of $h^3$.)

Substituting $h=2\text{ ft}$ and $\frac{dh}{dt} = -14 \text{ in min$^{-1}$}$ gives:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dV}{dt} &= \pi \left(\frac{4\cdot2}{15}\text{ ft}\right)^2 \left(-14 \text{ in min$^{-1}$}\right)\\
&= -\frac{896\pi}{225}\text{ ft$^{2}$ in min$^{-1}$}
\end{align*}$$

So I had to point out, what unit did you intend to use? Some may consider the absolute rate of change as $\frac{896\pi}{225}$ correct, if you had included its corresponding unit.

Comment: The correct units assumed by the problem is (ft)^3/min

Comment: @CompilingConfusion Then you should convert in to ft.

Comment: Thank you so much I did not realize that

Comment: @CompilingConfusion Either at $\frac{dh}{dt} = -14 \text{ in min$^{-1}$} = -14/12 \text{ ft min$^{-1}$}$, or at $\frac{dV}{dt} = \ldots \text{ ft$^{2}$ in min$^{-1}$} = \ldots /12 \text{ ft$^{3}$ min$^{-1}$}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS

$$ V= \frac{\pi}{3}r^2 h$$

Differentiate with respect to $t$

$$ \frac{r}{h}=\frac{\dot r}{\dot h }=\frac{4}{15}$$

$$ \dot V= \frac{\pi}{3}(2 r \dot r h + r^2\dot h) $$

Eliminate $r$,  plug in  $\dot r$ .

Comment: I plugged in $ \frac{4h}{15} $ for r.

Comment: @CompilingConfusion But this answer is pointing out that r also changes, so you can't just plug that value in for r and then only care about the rate of change of the height.

Comment: I don't understand, im trying to find  $$ \frac{dH}{dt}$$ right? The height im given is 2ft, while the rate of change in height is 14.

Comment: Why do you try to find height rate when it is already given ? (as   -14/12 ft/min ?) Also $H =h? $